# exception after update primefaces 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to update the primefaces 3.5 to 4.0 and is launching this exception.

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception: 
No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature:
java.lang.String resolveWidgetVar(java.lang.String)
```

Someone knows how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The function `String resolveWidgetVar(String )` in the given class, does not exist at all in PF 3.5, but it does in 4th version. Maybe you should ensure that the jars of the new version are well included in the classpath and recognized by the IDE.

Comment: You mean it doesn't exist in 4.0 but did in 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

It's old but in case someone come around and uses this. If you are using maven you should check your pom.xml prime faces dependency and verify the version upgrade you made. It resolved my issue after reading into the answer about it existing in the 4th version.